# Как ставить новые элементы RecyclerView в начало списка

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, recyclerview

Есть список RecyclerView. В нём хранятся недавние чаты. То есть если пользователь пишет другому пользователю сообщение, то этот чат сохранятся в список во фрагменте. Фрагмент получает список:

```
class MessagesFragment : Fragment() {

    private var userAdapter: UserAdapterSecond? = null
    private var mUsers: List<User>? = null
    private var usersChatList: List<ChatList>? = null
    lateinit var recycler_view_messages: RecyclerView
    private var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser? = null

    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages, container, false)


        recycler_view_messages = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_messages)
        recycler_view_messages.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recycler_view_messages.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)


        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser


        usersChatList = ArrayList()

        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("ChatList").child(firebaseUser!!.uid)
        ref!!.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot)
            {
                (usersChatList as ArrayList).clear()

                for (dataSnapshot in p0.children)
                {
                    val chatList = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatList::class.java)

                    (usersChatList as ArrayList).add(chatList!!)
                }
                retrieveChatList()
            }

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })


        return view
    }


    private fun retrieveChatList()
    {
        mUsers = ArrayList()

        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users")
        ref!!.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot)
            {
                (mUsers as ArrayList).clear()

                for (dataSnapshot in p0.children)
                {
                    val user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User::class.java)

                    for (eachChatList in usersChatList!!)
                    {
                        if (user!!.getUID().equals(eachChatList.getId()))
                        {
                            (mUsers as ArrayList).add(user!!)
                        }
                    }
                }
                userAdapter = UserAdapterSecond(context!!, (mUsers as ArrayList<User>), true)
                recycler_view_messages.adapter = userAdapter
            }

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })
    }
}
```

Если я написал пользователю А, чат сохранился в самом начале. Далее я пишу пользователю Б, чат сохраняется в самом начале, выше чата А. Если же я опять напишу пользователю А, то чат А так и останется ниже чата Б, а должен становиться самым первым. Как решить решить эту проблему?

Comment: Можно по разному. В вашем случае, наверное, подойдёт сортировка полученного списка по дате какой-либо. Например по дате последнего сообщения в чате с к-л юзером.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, ну это понятно. А вот как сам список сортировать в плане кода?

Comment: Это зависит от структуры ваших данных и наличия в них полей по которым можно сортировку произвести. Вроде бы в вашем случае ничего нужного нет (судя по тому, что отображаете вы список юзеров, а список чатов с юзерами вы получаете, но нигде не используете). Если бы вы отображали список чатов с юзерами и в объекте чата с юзером была бы дата последнего сообщения, то можно было бы так сделать: `val sorterUserChatList = usersChatList.sortBy { it.lastMessageDate }`.

Comment: Если в объекте чата с юзером нет даты, но есть список сообщений, в которых есть дата создания, то так: `val sorterUserChatList = usersChatList.sortBy { it.messagesList.maxBy { it.creationDate  } }`

Comment: Ну и да, на Firebase сложно построить что-то больше минимального прототипа. Оно мало того, что NoSQL, что накладывает кучу ограничений на то, что и как можно сделать (например нельзя получить длину массива, насколько мне известно.) но ещё и станет платным (иногда даже существенно дорогим) как только вы получите какое-то кол-во юзеров. Если вы планируете делать что-то более менее серьёзное (т.е. не просто учебный проект для тренировки), то вам стоит подумать над написанием и поднятием собственного сервера, содержащего всю нужную логику для обработки, хранения и выдачи данных.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, спасибо за советы. Пока это только школьный проект)